# Bases of Ideals With no Monomials

Tags: tropical-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, ac.commutative-algebra, co.combinatorics

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and $K[\underline{x}]$ its ring of polynomials in $n$ variables $x_1,\cdots, x_n$. Let $J\leq K[\underline{x}]$ be an ideal such that there are no monomials in $J$. Is there any characterization on a finite set of generators (probably a reduced Gröbner base) $G$ of $J$?

To rephrase my question, Is there a way to know when an ideal in $K[\underline{x}]$ has no monomials by just looking at a set of finitely many generators?

Comment: Let's think about the inverse: $J$ contains some monomial iff $J$ contains 
some power of $\langle \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \rangle$, iff $\sqrt{J}$ contains
$\langle \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \rangle$, iff $V(J)$ is contained in 
$V(\langle \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \rangle) =$ 
the union of the coordinate hyperplanes. I don't suppose your $J$ is a prime ideal...